# Example of two way databinding in dart with polymer.dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I see examples of one way data binding with the {{my_var}} format but, I do not see a way to bind the change from the HTML side back to the dart object. For example an input box text changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several examples on [Seth Ladd's GitHub space](https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples).

Here is a concrete example for a text input binding:

```
<polymer-element name="my-example">
  <template>
    <div>
      Type something: <input type="text" value="{{message}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      You typed {{message}}
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_example.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>



import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('my-example')
class MyExample extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  @observable String message;
}
```